# Android / Huawei: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/cust/xml/hw_launcher_load_icon.xml: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Tags: java, android, xml

I programmed a simple App an I alway get the Logcat message (system.err):

```
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/cust/xml/hw_launcher_load_icon.xml: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

I do not try to open the file. I do not have the problem on Nexus 4, only on the Huawei P6 (4.2.2). This is very annoying, because I can't see something in the LogCat-box, beause of this message.

I tried to see more with DDMS, but no success.

Thanks

Comment: This is probably not from your application at all, but from factory installed component - checking the log tag and/or process ID of the message vs. that which your app is currently running under will clarify.  Generally, you'll want to learn to use filters on logcat.

Comment: This message returns also in my apllication. So i can not filter by "Application Name"

Comment: What makes you believe that is the case?  It sounds like you are confused as to the meaning of the information presented by logcat.  that this is showing in your eclipse or whatever logcat window in no way implies that it is related to your application under development.  Checking the PID will clarify.

Comment: Both have the same PIDs(marked with ** **):
`01-28 23:34:10.061: W/System.err(**17243**): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/cust/xml/hw_launcher_load_icon.xml: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
01-28 23:34:10.221: E/TAG(**17243**): MyErrorLog`

Answer (score 5):

It's a bit late, but may be it helps other people who may still stumble across this:

This error is not an actual error of the app itself, it's a follow-up error of an uncaught exception within the app that actually crashed the app. Run the app again on a different device and/or emulator, reproduce the same steps that lead to this "FileNotFoundException", and you will actually see the real exception that was hidden on the Huawei.
I don't know what Huawei is doing there, but it's definitely not helping developers writing and testing software.

Comment: in my case on other devices I can not see any other Exception. But on huawei it crashes same