# trying to get rid of a persistent log warning debugging on Huawei Ascend P6

Tags: android, adb, logcat

I used to test my app on SGS 2 I9100 (4.1.2), after the device became defect I purchased a Huawei Ascend P6 (4.2). I have to always connect it in HiSuite mode which launches their annoying sync software on PC, USB debugging won't work otherwise. Ok, I got used to it but anytime I run my app I see this log (marked as WARN) and tagged with my app (the app still runs without any issues):

```
  02-08 13:30:34.532: W/System.err(5815): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/cust/xml/hw_launcher_load_icon.xml: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
  02-08 13:30:34.532: W/System.err(5815):   at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
  02-08 13:30:34.532: W/System.err(5815):   at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:109)
  02-08 13:30:34.532: W/System.err(5815):   at android.content.res.ResourcesEx.readDefaultConfig(ResourcesEx.java:808)
  02-08 13:30:34.532: W/System.err(5815):   at android.content.res.ResourcesEx.<init>(ResourcesEx.java:741)
 02-08 13:30:34.532: W/System.err(5815):    at android.app.ActivityThread.getTopLevelResources(ActivityThread.java:1721)
 02-08 13:30:34.532: W/System.err(5815):    at android.app.ActivityThread.getTopLevelResources(ActivityThread.java:1752)
 02-08 13:30:34.532: W/System.err(5815):    at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:485)
02-08 13:30:34.532: W/System.err(5815):     at android.app.ContextImpl.init(ContextImpl.java:1911)
02-08 13:30:34.532: W/System.err(5815):     at android.app.ContextImpl.init(ContextImpl.java:1904)
02-08 13:30:34.532: W/System.err(5815):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4269)
02-08 13:30:34.532: W/System.err(5815):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:145)
02-08 13:30:34.532: W/System.err(5815):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1306)
 02-08 13:30:34.532: W/System.err(5815):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-08 13:30:34.532: W/System.err(5815):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-08 13:30:34.532: W/System.err(5815):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5095)
02-08 13:30:34.532: W/System.err(5815):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 02-08 13:30:34.532: W/System.err(5815):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-08 13:30:34.532: W/System.err(5815):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
02-08 13:30:34.532: W/System.err(5815):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
02-08 13:30:34.532: W/System.err(5815):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-08 13:30:34.532: W/System.err(5815): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
02-08 13:30:34.536: W/System.err(5815):     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
02-08 13:30:34.536: W/System.err(5815):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
02-08 13:30:34.536: W/System.err(5815):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:400)
02-08 13:30:34.536: W/System.err(5815):     ... 19 more
   02-08 13:30:35.053: W/System.err(5815): Invalid int: ""
```

The problem is that this warning in the ONLY thing I see in LogCat, it somehow blocks all other messages even if a real exception occurs. To be exact: yes, I see only the message posted above and nothing else every time I run the app. As far as I understood, the system tries to get some resource which isn't even part of my project. But I have no clue why any other LogCat output does not appear. Anyone any idea what that is and how to fix it?

Comment: Does it occur repeatedly while your app is running? That'd explain why you can't see your own logs. Also, did you try putting a file at the path shown in the stacktrace?

Comment: it appears immediately after I start my app. Then it seems the session filter I have set up for my app just dies. Example - timestamp 11:20, this warning appears. Then no matter what and for how long I do with my app, no other messages will appear. That message at 11:20 will stay the only one. Yes, I also tried to create `/data/cust/xml/hw_launcher_load_icon.xml` in my project, putting some random drawable there - with no effect at all

Comment: Did you also create a file at this path on your phone's file system? (you might need root for that)

Comment: where exactly on the file system? It seems I can only access directories contained in the directory which `getExternalStorageDirectory()` returns. That is `/storage/emulated/0`  There's also an /Android/data folder but I doubt it's the correct one

Comment: I mean literally at /data/cust/xml/... As I said before, you probably need root to write to this directory, but this will most likely solve your problem.

Comment: what is the parent directory of `/data` dir that you are talking about?

Comment: / ... the root directory of the file system in Linux

Comment: alright I gotta check xda for rooting instructions for this device.. btw, how do I write this file to this location? The only thing I have in mind is writing my own mini-app that will request SU permission and write the file. Any faster solutions?

Comment: you should only need to do it once, after rooting, open a shell with `adb shell` request SU, navigate to directory and `cp localfile phonefile`

Comment: @TristanBurnside ok I created an empty file in that dir, same exception.. but now it says "open failed (permission denied". If I only could find the correct contents for this file

Comment: @Droidman - you need to change the permissions on the file so that your application can read is.  Look up the "chmod" shell command.

Comment: @StephenC yeah, already figured it out. But now the same sh1t, this time the XmlPullParser fails (sure, cause the file is empty and I don't know what should be inside).

Comment: @Droidman copy one of your layout files in there. It'll probably fail because it's missing a specific tag, but you can reverse engineer the file exception by exception...

Answer (score 1):

As a person developing on a Huawei Ascend P6, this error only happens for me if I include a theme *that is a theme inside the `android` namespace* when defining an Activity (or the entire Application), leaving me to think that theme support is broken on Huawei's Android 4.2.2.

Comment: me too :( i have this issue in my Huawei p6

Comment: I removed themes in android namespace but it doesn't help at all.

Answer (score 1):

See my answer on the SO question below, which is basically the same question as this one (I just cannot mark this here one as duplicate):

[Android / Huawei: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/cust/xml/hw_launcher_load_icon.xml: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21415630/android-huawei-java-io-filenotfoundexception-data-cust-xml-hw-launcher-load/28602073#28602073)

Comment: thanks for your effort m8, upvoting. But I develop on Nexus devices only for a long time already, got tired of 3rd-party buggy crap

Comment: :) Totally understandable. I am testing on a variety of devices, and one of them is such a P6. Took me a while to figure this nasty bugger out, and now I usually do the real debugging on other devices, and only do compliance testing on the P6.